# Access VBA - Argument not optional - backcolor

Tags: ms-access, vba, rgb

I have a table where the user can select a colour scheme for their database

```
ID | Colour     | SelectedScheme
---|------------|--------------
1  | 136,207,39 | Yes
```

Then on my form I have the following on the current events tab

```
Dim RGBcolor As Long
RBGcolor = DLookup("Colour", "SelectedScheme")
Me.boxheader.BackColor = RGB(RGBcolor)
```

but I'm getting the Argument not optional error. any idea?

Answer (score 2):

Arguments of RGB function are numeric, not string, and there should be 3 of them:

```
RGB(136,207,39)
```

You are trying to pass one string argument.
You can use `Split` function for extracting color values from string:

```
Me.boxheader.BackColor = RGB(Split(RGBcolor,",")(0),Split(RGBcolor,",")(1),Split(RGBcolor,",")(2))
```

Answer (score 1):

The Dlookup function accepts these arguments:

- FieldName: a field, calculation, control on a form, or function that you wish to return;
- TableName: the set of records. This can be a table or a query name;
- Criteria (Optional): It is the WHERE clause to apply to the TableName.

And the RGB functions accepts these three:

- red: the red component of the color;
- green: the green component of the color;
- blue: the blue component of the color.

I would suggest you to use three different columns for the component color in your table:

```
ID | ColourR | ColourG | ColourB | SelectedScheme
---|---------|---------|---------|---------------
1  | 136     |207      | 39      | Yes
```

Your event can be written as this:

```
Me.boxheader.BackColor = RGB(
  DLookup("ColourR", "SchemaTableName", "SelectedScheme=TRUE"),
  DLookup("ColourG", "SchemaTableName", "SelectedScheme=TRUE"),
  DLookup("ColourB", "SchemaTableName", "SelectedScheme=TRUE")
)
```

this will select the color from the table SchemaTableName where the field SelectedScheme is set to true.

Answer (score 1):

The `RGB()` function expects 3 numbers, but your code supplies a single string value.  That is the cause of the *"Argument not optional"* compile error.

Construct a new string which includes the `RGB()` function plus your string of numbers.  Submit that new string to `Eval()` ...

```vb
Me.boxheader.BackColor = Eval("RGB(" & RBGcolor & ")")
```